# How can I do this with page redirection?

Tags: php, url-routing

I have a revision website, it has stuff for multiple school subjects. I am starting to develop subject pages, these will have stuff only for that subject. e.g. a physics page

Anyway, what I am trying to do is let people type in `www.myWebsite.com/history` or `www.myWebsite.com/ict` - or what ever. And them get redirected to the appropriate page.

From that it sounds really simple, I would just put a file called history.php in my public_html home directory, right?

But my home directory is super organised, with everything in nice sub folders. I want to but all the subject pages in a sub folder called 'subjects' (imaginative name :p ).

How can I put these pages in the sub folder, yet still let the user access them from the URL examples above?

Comment: See this answer, it is similar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507132/htaccess-remove-php-and-keep-query-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way to do this is to use a Front Controller. You can re-route all requests to one file (typically index.php) via htaccess and then from there grab the URI (the /itc, /history etc.) and use it to direct the request to the appropriate script.

Check this out, should get you started.
http://www.technotaste.com/blog/simple-php-front-controller/

Once you figure that out, you will want to compare the differences between dynamic and static invocation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

you've got to do a url rewrite for the same. google out mod_rewrite and you'll get the examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running under Apache, mod_rewrite is probably the most direct approach to accomplishing this.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Basically create a .htaccess file in the root that maps the URI segment to the appropriate php file in your 'subjects' directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case where you could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), so the web server you're using will redirect the user to the appropiate directory. You can either keep the rewrite list manually or dynamically using regexes.