# htaccess remove .php and keep query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

Here is my .htaccess file right now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

This works in the fact that it makes my pages accessible when not using the .php extension.

```
Old = domain.com/test.php
New = domain.com/test
```

The bad thing is that when I send get data with the following link the data is not passed. I thought the QSA option did that, whats the deal?

```
domain.com/test?id=1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matching the entire query string and appending it to your new URL using a back-reference should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more simple solution. We use it on our team project. It will work not only in the root, but in any directory of your website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing `id` then you have to use this code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test.php?id=$1
```

now you can access

```
domain.com/test?id=1
```

from

```
domain.com/test/1
```

Comment: what if this variable always changes or there are different variable names, also I would need to pass data on other pages as well. There isn't just a rule saying take out the .php and leave everything else?

Comment: you can also pass id=2, id=3... so on.. to access id=2, use `domain.com/test/2`

Comment: and if you are different variable, or 2 variable, just change rule to `RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/(.*)$ /test.php?id=$1&othervariable=$2`